# JQuery inline dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there an easy way to convert a standart popup dialog into an inline  dialog?

Comment: What do you mean by "standard popup dialog" exactly? alert()? prompt()? confirm()?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

For example you can use colorbox. Examples: http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example1/index.html

With the iframed or ajax option it's very easy.

Comment: Colorbox looks like a standart dialog (blocks out the entire page when pops up), that's what I already have. I need to convert it to inline dialog, just like the one I'm typing this message into right now. But thanks for response!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2N4r7/1/) that demonstrates the technique that I think you want using the jQuery `after()` function.